# How to iterate through a listbox and change forecolor for each item individually C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a listbox that contains names and followed by either (Online) or (Offline), Ex. Luffy (Online). I am trying to iterate thorough the listbox and access each item individually and check if it contains online or offline, and based on that i change the forecolor of the item that contains (Online) to green, and leave the rest as white.

I used a forloop to access the items in the listbox, however i cant access the forecolor of each individual item of the listbox. Here is the code.

```
        for(int i = 0; i< list_friends.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list_friends.Items[i].ToString().Contains("(Online)") == true)
            {
                //write code to make forecolor green
            }
            else
            {
                //write code to make forecolor white
            }
        }
```

Comment: what's the question here?

Comment: Maybe you can consider change `listbox` to `ListView` or `DataGridView` to have more flexibility.

Comment: my question is how do i change the forecolor of each item of of the listbox. I cant access the forecolor property so i was hoping there is another way to change the color of the listbox item

Comment: Yea i figured i might have to change the listbox to a DataGridView. But is there anyway to do what im trying to do in a listbox or is it impossible.

Comment: there is currently no native support for different colors per item in ListBox. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.forecolor?view=windowsdesktop-7.0
there are ways to code what you want, but why not use the tools .Net already includes like @HeinzSiahaan wrote?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ForeColor property of individual items in the ListBox.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list_friends.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string itemText = list_friends.Items[i].ToString();
    if (itemText.Contains("(Online)"))
    {
        list_friends.Items[i] = itemText.Replace("(Online)", "");
        list_friends.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        list_friends.Items[i] = itemText;
        list_friends.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your help. The solution you sent makes sense and looks correct but i get an error saying "The type or namespace name 'ListBoxItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: Check the updated code once.

Comment: I appreciate your time and help. I tried the updated code. It works. However it changes the entire listbox forcolor not the individual item. I think as Mohobo stated above, "there is currently no native support for different colors per item in ListBox".